# boto3 Multiple ways to wait for an instance to be ready, which is the correct one?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm investigating a sporadic bug with `send_command()` and I think it might be related to the instance not being completely ready before sending the command.

I was using this to wait for the instance:

```
instance.wait_until_running()
```

However I have also seen:

```
waiter = ec2.get_waiter('instance_running')
waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[instance.id])
```

and:

```
waiter = ec2.get_waiter('instance_status_ok')
waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[instance.id])
```

What is the difference/correct way to wait for an instance to be completely ready to send a command?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two `Waiter`s is that the `InstanceStatusOk` waits for AWS to perform the additional [system and instance checks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html) on your running instance.

Whether the instance is "completely ready" when it is in the `Running` state may depend on any bootstrapping you do on the instance after launch.  You would have to provide more details on that, along with a more precise definition of "completely ready" in your context (e.g., a specific command and the expected result).

Also, some more [evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on the "sporadic bug" you are experiencing would enable us to reproduce it and perhaps help fix it.